# Entities inheritance in OData

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a PoC service similar [odata.org's demo service](http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/(S(eq1ncar1ktn55khwjrukic3c))/OData.svc/$metadata)
So in thier demo they have a Person base type and Customer and Employee derived types.

I want to query for all (or filtered) the instances of the derived type Employee.
Since the spec says "An entity can be a member of at most one entity set at any given point in time.   Entity sets provide entry points into the data model."
The entry point for Employees is through the Persons EntitySet, so far so good.
But I'm just can't find a way to filter by the @odata.type.

I've tried many queries like:

`/Persons?$filter=@odata.type eq ODataDemo.Employee`
`/Persons?$filter=odata.type eq ODataDemo.Employee`
`/Persons?$filter=type eq ODataDemo.Employee`
...
(The root is: http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/(S(eq1ncar1ktn55khwjrukic3c))/OData.svc/Persons )

But nothing returned 200 OK status code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as following Uri:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/(S(eq1ncar1ktn55khwjrukic3c))/OData.svc/Persons/ODataDemo.Employee
```

The related spec:
[Addressing Derived Types](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793786)

Comment: +1 You're right, I read about it and tried it in my demo and it didn't work and forgot to use it on the odata.org demo. but indeed it's working. But do you know why I'm getting 404 when trying it on my demo? I don't have something special.

Comment: @gdoron are you using web api to write OData service? V3 or V4?

Comment: I think the problem might be in my entity framework code first layer. I'll check it next week when I'll be in the office again. Thank you!